# Как на php взять информацию (какую-то определённую из множества ненужной) с любого сайта и заключить в переменную

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
При написании кода возник вопрос. Как на php взять информацию (какую-то определённую из множества ненужной) с любого сайта и заключить в переменную.
Если возможно, прошу показать на примере.

Comment: вот в этой статье подробно описано [Учимся парсить сайты с библиотекой PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://xdan.ru/Uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser.html)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Может не всегда работать. Еще есть Curl расширение под PHP, а также можно напрямую работать с сокетами.